# Why this program doesn't report parse exception?

Tags: java, date

To match the date against three date formats:

```
import java.text.ParseException;
   import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

   public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    validateDateFormat("2010-01-01 22:kk");
}

/**
 * Checks if the date is valid or not.
 * 
 * @param stringDate
 * @return date format of the string date passed.
 */
private static String validateDateFormat(String stringDate) {
    String dateFormat = "";

    /**
     * Set the permissible formats.
     */
    String[] permissFormats = new String[]{"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", 
    "yyyy-MM-dd", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"};

    /**
     * Loop through array of formats and validate using JAVA API.
     */
    for (int i = 0; i < permissFormats.length; i++) {
        try {
            SimpleDateFormat sdfObj = new SimpleDateFormat(permissFormats[i]);
            sdfObj.setLenient(true);
            sdfObj.parse(stringDate);
            dateFormat = permissFormats[i];
            System.out.println("the parsed date "
                    + "format is "+dateFormat);
            break;
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            if (i == permissFormats.length - 1) {
                System.out.println("Parse Exception: DateFormat for "
                        + "Date Value :" + stringDate + " is invalid" + e);
            }
        }
    }

    return dateFormat;

}
```

}

**OUTPUT:**

```
the parsed date format is yyyy-MM-dd
```

How to match the format completely if given?

Comment: Because you're only outputting the exception when `(i == permissFormats.length - 1)`. Do you want to output the exception details at only that time, or for other use cases?

Comment: `setLenient(false)` might detect a month 14.

Comment: No, my intention was that if I give the `validateDateFormat("2010-01-01 22:10:kk");`, it should report an error. But it just discards the `HH:mm:ss` and takes the format `"yyyy-MM-dd"` for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you ignore the exception when is not last array element here:

```
if (i == permissFormats.length - 1) {
```

If you do:

```
} catch (ParseException e) {
    System.out.println("Parse Exception: DateFormat for " + "Date Value :" + stringDate + " is invalid" + e);
}
```

Will throw:

```
Parse Exception: DateFormat for Date Value :2010-01-01 22:kk is invalidjava.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2010-01-01 22:kk"
the parsed date format is yyyy-MM-dd
```

Corrected, if you execute:

```
validateDateFormat("2010-01-01 22:00:00");
```

Will answer:

```
the parsed date format is yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss
```

> Then how to match the entire string.

```
if (permissFormats[i].length == stringDate.length) {
    SimpleDateFormat sdfObj = new SimpleDateFormat(permissFormats[i]);
    sdfObj.setLenient(true);
    sdfObj.parse(stringDate);
}
```

Comment: Then how to match the entire string. My intention was that if I give the `validateDateFormat("2010-01-01 22:10:kk");`, it should report an error. But it just discards the `HH:mm:ss` and takes the format `"yyyy-MM-dd"` for it.

Comment: previously compare both string and format lenght and decide if parsing, check my edit

Answer (score 3):

You have lenient parsing set to true:

```
sdfObj.setLenient(true);
```

> [public void setLenient(boolean lenient)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#setLenient-boolean-)
>
> Specify whether or not date/time parsing is to be lenient. With
>   lenient parsing, **the parser may use heuristics to interpret inputs**
>   that do not precisely match this object's format. With strict parsing,
>   inputs must match this object's format.

also note that [DateFormat#parse](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#parse-java.lang.String-) docs says:

> The method may not use the entire text of the given string.

Edit: in answer to your comment

Alternatively, you can simply use [DateValidator](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-validator/apidocs/org/apache/commons/validator/routines/DateValidator.html) with strcit parsing:

```
DateValidator v = new DateValidator(true, DateFormat.FULL);
v.validate(value, pattern);
```

`validate()` returns the parsed `Date` if valid or `null` if invalid.

Comment: Then how to match the entire string. My intention was that if I give the `validateDateFormat("2010-01-01 22:10:kk");`, it should report an error. But it just discards the `HH:mm:ss` and takes the format `"yyyy-MM-dd"` for it.

Comment: I would use [DateValidator](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-validator/apidocs/org/apache/commons/validator/routines/DateValidator.html) from [Commons Validator](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-validator/)